# How to convert ISearchResponse <dynamic> to C# Class Object?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

How to convert [ISearchResponse](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/Search/Search/SearchResponse.cs)  to C# Class Object.

I am trying to convert  to Class Object where my Class name will be dynamic.

```
ISearchResponse<dynamic> bResponseNewLoop = 
    objElastic.Search<dynamic>(s => s
        .Index("index1")
        .Type("DOCTYPE")
        .From(0)
        .Size(10)
        .Source(sr => sr.Include(RequiredFields)));
```

From above Response , i want to convert the response object to class object and The class name i am retriving  from xml file.

Answer (score 7):

In newer NEST versions we introduced `IDocument` which allows you to do lazy deserialization to the proper type.

```
var response = objElastic.Search<IDocument>(s => s
     .Index("index1")
     .Type("DOCTYPE")
     .From(0).Size(10)
     .Source(sr => sr.Include(RequiredFields)
);
```

Now on response you can loop over all the `.Hits` and inspect the hit metadata and use that to deserialize to the type that you want. e.g

```
.Hits.First().Source.As<MyDocument>()
```

`As<>()` is a method on `IDocument`

Comment: As of now, we are using NEST 4.0. But this IDocument is not suppported with above syntax in 4.0.Can you please suggest which version of the NEST is supporting this.

Comment: This has been part of `NEST` since version [1.5.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/1.5.0)

Comment: I just dove into version 6 and there is no `IDocument`. To make sure I compared with version 1.5 where it exists. The `IDocument` is commented as a side effect of 'inner hits' in the [release notes](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/1.5.0); and 'inner hits' is/was experimental.

Comment: Version 7 has ILazyDocument