# Is it possible to use ElasticSearch.Net or Nest for dynamic response

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-net

Is there a `client.Read(...)` without generics? I have found none, neither in [Nest nor ElasticSearch.Net](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net).

---

Version 1.5 has an [`IDocument`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160928/how-to-convert-isearchresponse-dynamic-to-c-sharp-class-object) that might solve my problem but I cannot use that version with Elasticsearch5.5.

All examples, version 5 and 6, of ElasticSearch.Net and Nest require me to know the format of the response as generic at compile time. E.g. `Read<Customer>`(...)

My problem is that the *we do not know the format* of the database and we don't know the format of the output; but it should all be configurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` as the generic type if the response is truly dynamic.

In 5.x, this will be Json.NET's `JObject` type under the covers (so you could use `JObject` instead if you prefer).

In 6.x, `dynamic` will also work but the actual type will be an internal `JObject` type. If you would prefer to work with Json.NET's `JObject` type, you can [hook up Json.NET as the serializer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) using the [NEST.JsonNetSerializer nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/), to use as the serializer for your documents and then use its `JObject` type as per 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

(Feels strange to answer my own question but I want to show the resulting code for future reference.)

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(@"http://localnhost:9200"))
    .DefaultIndex("myindex");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var res = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
    .AllTypes());

var rows = res.Documents;
Assert.IsTrue(rows.Count >= 1);

dynamic row = res.Documents.First();
Assert.AreEqual("50.7031526", row.POSITION.lat.ToString()); // It is case sensitive.
Assert.AreEqual(50.7031526, (double)row.POSITION.lat); // Convert to type explicitly.
```